# Retrieve data from jquery HTML method into an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I start learning jquery and have the following code to getting the data from my database, it is corrected display what I want from the database in the 'div tag' below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            // function to get data from the database
            function getData()
            {
                $('#num').hide();
                $.post('getData.php',{rev: form.select.value},
                  function(output){
                          $('#num').html(output).fadeIn(700);        
                  });
            }
 </script>
 ....
 <div id="num"></div>
 .......
```

The jquery html method displays as a string (e.g: 1 2 3).
Now I want to save the contents of jquery html method into an array so I can access it for future data usage, is there any way to establish that ? Thanks for your helps !!!

Comment: why are you trying to store that in a separate storage.? Any time you can access it through the `.html()`

Comment: could I be able to access only the first value of the contents ? e.g: 1. I want to use that value for something else

Comment: Can you show the contents? is it exactly `1 2 3` - separated by spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use `output.split(' ')`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arr;
        // function to get data from the database
        function getData()
        {
            $('#num').hide();
            $.post('getData.php',{rev: form.select.value},
              function(output){
                      $('#num').html(output).fadeIn(700);
                      arr = output.split(' ');
              });
        }
</script>
```

You can access the first element using `output.split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` or `JSON.parse` here:

Using JSON.parse:

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + output + "]");
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

This gives you an Array of numbers.

or

```
output.split(" ");
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

This gives you an Array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, "**it is corrected display what I want from the database in the 'div tag' below**" so you don't want to split or re-format, you want to "**save the contents of jquery html method into an array so I can access it for future data usage**".

What you're asking is a little ambiguous still. Do you mean this? Save the data in a variable.

```
var somedata;

$.post('getData.php',{rev: form.select.value},
    function(output){
        $('#num').html(output).fadeIn(700);        
        somedata=output; // but then why not just use the var output?
    });
});

// somedata can be accessed at any time
```

Or this? The data is a CSV using space as the delimiter, so `1 2 3`, save that as an array

```
var somedata;

$.post('getData.php',{rev: form.select.value},
    function(output){
        $('#num').html(output).fadeIn(700);        
        somedata=output.split(' ');
    });
});

// you can access somedata[0] which = 1, but only after the $.post has happened
```